# How do I remove the Donki extension from Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Chrome reinstalled

[image]

The original facebook text that I clicked on:

[image]

My OS is Linux Ubuntu 16.04 I think.

I guess I'm looking for the terminal command to remove an extension from Chrome (Chromium seems to have been unaffected)

An arty friend sent me a message of his video, so I clicked on the link to the "video" and then this window opened saying I need to add this "donki extension" to the browser in order to view the video, so I went along with that, then this thing just took over my browser (Chrome) messaging all my other friends on facebook. He'd received the same thing from another friend (another artist)

My friend said that facebook offered to clean it off his computer and remove the extension - "it was all very easy" he said (on Windows 7).

Does anyone have any idea what I should do??

Comment: with the computer on it's still sending this same message

Comment: There are LOTS of info about that malware... And there's no "sudo command"... `sudo` has the sole purpose of elevating privileges (as root) in order to install or make other changes in the system. You should start by removing the unwanted extensions in Google Chrome itself. It may or may not be enough but that's a start. Expect it to come back as soon as you use Chrome in an infected Windows machine.

Comment: Have you checked fro this extension in the the extension section of chrome itself?

Comment: Does the infection link still work? I am pretty curious about spinning up a VM and trying it.

Comment: Why would you install a random browser extension that someone suggests on the internet without explanation? You wouldn't stick random needles into you body just because someone tells you to unless that someone is your/a doctor and has a somewhat reasonable explanation, would you?

Comment: @DavidFoerster as far as I understand, we are talking about an extension that self-propagates by Facebook Messenger. I.e. the OP probably got the link "from" one of their FB friend. Could be victim of a phishing like attack.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: "Phising" by definition requires the cooperation and interaction of the (unsuspecting) victim. The extension doesn't "self-propagate" as much as it impersonates its victims to solicit the complicity of its next victims(s).

Comment: @DavidFoerster it sends messages automatically, of course they need to install the extensions. As for why OP "would install" it, my comment already provides an explanation.

Comment: Related analysis by Kaspersky Labs: https://securelist.com/new-multi-platform-malwareadware-spreading-via-facebook-messenger/81590/

Comment: To answer your entertaining but somewhat narcissistic question David, I normally wouldn't touch such an odd looking link, but we'd just been talking about his new exhibition, I thought this was the promotional video thereof.

Andrea feel free to try that link (in the photo above) I was going to copy and paste it for you but facebook has removed it. Good old facebook :-)

Comment: MY original question explained all that but someone decided they should remove it hence your confusion, David :/

Answer (score 4):

In order to remove or disable any extension in Chrome, you must first visit the settings page for your installed extensions at *`chrome://extensions`* which can be accessed by typing the same into your search/URL box.

This is a local settings page within your Chrome browser and you do not need to be connected to a network to access it.

[image: Chrome extensions page]

The list of installed extensions on your browser and an enable/disable option for each extension will be displayed.

There will be a bin icon alongside the extension which you wish to uninstall (in this case the Donki extension) which will allow you to completely remove that extension from your browser.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your reply!

Well if I Google donki, something comes up about a restaurant in Europe.  If I Google donki extension, only this post Comes up.

As for your fine suggestion, that was the first thing I did, only it wouldn't let me IN to extensions, each time I clicked on it the tab would open for a split second then disappear.

So I uninstalled chrome, reinstalled it and the screen shot is of how it looks now... It won't work (except for sending out the same messages)

Suddenly I remembered "chrome had saved my credit card details" so I rang the bank to put a hold on it.

Comment: I can't even get into settings now

Comment: Another interesting development is the disappearance of my wireless icon from the top right hand corner of the screen....

Comment: @AndrewBoyd: Could you please edit your question, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Chrome and move your Chrome browser configuration out of the way:

   ```
   mv ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome-infected
   ```
2. Start Chrome and check if the browser extension is still installed and active. If you can't open the extension list that's a good sign that the extension is still active. If that's the case please edit your question and add the pertaining information for further probing.